# Is it able to get all activities of an user?

Tags: getstream-io

I read the doc and try to get all the activities of a user(not the user self), but the returned json is

```
{
  "detail":"You don't have permission to do this",
  "status_code":403,
  "code":17,
  "exception":"NotAllowedException",
  "duration":"0.13ms"
}
```

This is the code I am using,

```
let feed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "public", userId: "7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2")
feed.get() { result in
    try? result.get().results
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to get all activities of another user. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr: Yes, possible.

It's a permission issue in your application. By default, users can only read their own feed. However, you can get it changed by contacting to [support](https://getstream.io/support). Then, users will be able to read the feed of other users. Please mention the `feed_group` you want to make readable.

So, there are two types of feeds in your application:

- user: individual activities of a user go to this feed and support will enable it to be readable by anybody.
- timeline: what a user sees by following other feeds. As far as I understand, it doesn't need to be readable by others since it will be specific to one user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to upgrade my plan to get support to change it for me?

Comment: You can stay in your plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. It depends on your flow, but probably instead of getting all activities from other users, the current user can follow others and get their activities.

**Tap on avatar**

I suppose you use Stream Activity Feed Components. You can subclass `FlatFeedViewController` that based on `BaseFlatFeedViewController` and you can override method: `func updateAvatar(in cell: PostHeaderTableViewCell, activity: T)` to add a callback for avatar button:

```swift
override func updateAvatar(in cell: PostHeaderTableViewCell, activity: T) {
    cell.updateAvatar(with: activity.actor) { avatarButton in
        // ... open the detail view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, users now are able to see all activities of all the other users they have followed.  But what I also would like to do is to click a user's avatar and show the profile and all activities of the user. So this is not possible, right? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand this button click event. Is there any way to get all the activities of a specific user? For example, I followed userA and userB, I can see activities they've posted in this feed group, what I would like to do is clicking userA and retrieving all activities of the userA. Is this possible to do? Thanks.